# Lattice Gas Automata and Galilean Invariance

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lattice-model, galilean-relativity, invariants

I have been studying [Lattice Gas Automata methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_gas_automaton) [(also this)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11747817.pdf), and every time I read up on their drawbacks, I see that they are not Galilean invariant and that the simulations have statistical noise. My question is, why is the case?

How do you prove that a lattice gas method is not Galilean invariant? Every proof of Galilean invariance I have seen is for two particles in different inertial frames, and then they prove that the force on both of these particles is the same. Why does this break for a lattice method? Furthermore, what is the consequence of Galilean invariance being broken? How is the physics affected?

And one final question: What is the reason for statistical noise in such simulations, and where does it take place?

Comment: You link to the wikipedia page where this is written. Have you looked at the book cited there? Namely, Succi's "The Lattice Boltzmann Equation". I just checked and, as wikipedia claims, this is discussed in more details in Section 2.5 of the book. I think that it would be rather pointless to repeat what it says here.